can we load multiple file formats in vertica external table?
I am trying to load CSV and Parquet format files into one external table in Vertica DB but not finding any options, in worst case planning to load it in two different tables and make a union but union execution is taking too much time to load the data. can someone guide me the best approach available in Vertica ?

The CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE foo(...) AS COPY FROM ...  command allows for only one source - platform and directory - and one format.
As CSV, even with apportioned load, tends to be intensive - meaning slow - in the parsing phase anyway, especially if you want to use selective filters, you might just get enough performance in a UNION SELECT of an external Parquet and an external CSV table.
However, if your licensing scheme and data adding strategy allows for regular data loads into Vertica internal ROS tables, consider creating a ROS table and regular COPY from CSV and COPY from Parquet commands.
